# Adding contact to WP8 with Facebook/Twitter infos

Tags: c#, facebook, twitter, windows-phone-8, contacts

Let's say that I have some infos about someone and I want to add them to my contacts using my app.

The infos may be:

- Name
- Surname
- Email
- Facebook Name (and/or Facebook user ID)
- Twitter Name

Now, using `SaveContactTask` I'm able to save the first three (and a lot of other things), but how do I link this new contact with his Facebook's infos?

And what if, when I add the new contact, I still have not the new contact in my Facebook's friends?

I know that the question may sound stupid, but I'm trying to learn stuff about WP8 and I want my app to be able to create new contacts and link them with Facebook (doesn't matter if they're linked when I add them or some time later).

Using a custom `ContactStore` is not what I want (it's ok if the user has to confirm the new contact and I don't want it to be removed when i delete the app).

So, to summarize, how can I create something like a *unified contact* using `SaveContactTask` starting from some basic data plus Facebook's ID?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem while trying to get contacts list and save new contacts. i have been looking for any kind of solution but i believe its not possible for now. You can either save contact by SaveContactTask or you can use ContactStore. Both approach has its pros and cons but they wont allow you to do exactly what you want. There are too many limitations. I think its a shame how contacts at WP8 can by managed from code but its what it is and for now there is nothing that we can do.